# Timer call in C# stops into to a Textbox

Tags: c#

I'm working on chat software in C# 2010 where all incoming messages are being received by a fixed timer. When I type any message for sending to the user and during my sentence typing if incoming message timer call comes everything stops for few seconds and then resume again.

Is there any way to make timer and input to textbox independent ?

Comment: I suppose that the timer exists on the UI thread. You might try to put it into another thread and work asynchronously.

Comment: @Jens H, That is what i thought too, but a timer is running on a own thread right?

Comment: Use timer of System.Threading class, it will give you best performance because it will run on other thread.

Comment: @MichaelOverhorst: I think it depends on the type of timer, it might be just nother task or in a different thread. fawad has not yet told us about the used techologies here. But on second thought a 'Timer' might **NOT** be the best solution anyway. *See my post below.*

Comment: I'm using winforms timer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of System.Forms.Timer use System.Timers.Timer. System.Forms.Timer will run in the UI thread where as System.Timers.Timer runs in a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about it, a timer might not be the best solution.

I suggest using some kind messaging system. A windows built-in technology to be used with .NET would be the Microsoft Message Queue.

There are existing frameworks that sit on top of the MSMQ to make working with it more comfortable, like [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/) or the open source [MassTransit](http://www.ohloh.net/p/masstransit).

This would decouple receiving from your UI thread and enable you for a more responsive UI on the client application.

Comment: Thank you so much but i dont want to use any third party plugin for this. i want to remain in C# environment.

Comment: @fawad: In that case you can still use the pure MSMQ functionality, no third party necessary. It is already out-of-the-box usable and part of C#/.NET. The basic principles are simple to learn. Examples for getting you started with plain MSMQ here: http://benmcevoy.com.au/blog/getting-started-with-msmq or combined with WCF here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/motleyqueue/archive/2009/05/31/msmq-and-wcf-getting-started.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you are using winforms then try to get message in seperate thread

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetMessage));
thread.Start();

public void GetMessage()
{
     //Message showing code goes here 
      Thread.Sleep(10000);
      GetMessage();
}
```

Comment: In form constructor i have declared Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetMessage));
thread.Start(); but it only executes one. What can be wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12485/discussion-between-nighil-and-fawad)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the timer independent, you need what the timer does to be.

Inside your timer.Tick event add this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
{
  //do what you need to do here ie.
      string something ="Hello";

      this.BeginInvoke( new Action(() =>
         {
             //update textbox here
             textBox1.Text=something;
         }));

 });
```

You will need this namespace

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Comment: Timer is primarily used for receiving messages and textbox is independent of timer. Now please suggest.

Comment: Your going to have to show us how you update the textBox then.  How can the textbox be independent of the timer?  The timer checks if there is a message, then it updates the textBox right?  If the textbox update is in a method, run the method where I have textBox1.Text=something.  If you are still getting the hiccup, then the problem is in the Method.  The answer will be easy, we just need a little more information on how you currently achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Although the already posted suggestions all are directed to the same problem, the actual cause of your application hangs was not directly mentioned here yet.

This is, simply put, **too much work in the same thread**.

In your case, the timer event is handled on the UI thread and causes some CPU load and therefore the input in the UI controls slows down because the precious CPU time is taken away to whatever happens in the `TimerTick` event handling method.

The solution therefore is to use **multiple** threads.

If you need to keep the timer architecture instead of using the MSMQ - which I would still strongly suggest - I recommend you to this MSDN article: [Give Your .NET-based Application a Fast and Responsive UI with Multiple Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300429.aspx)

The article is 'a few days old', but the principles remain absolutely valid today.

If you are working in a .NET 4.x version, you can also use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to make working with multiple threads easier.

The upcoming .NET 4.5 also offers the even more comfortable await and asyc keywords: [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).